# filter in scapy function sniff() says libpcap is not available

Tags: python, filtering, scapy, sniffing

I was playing around with the Scapy sniff function and I wanted to add a filter into the parameters. So I added this filter:

```
pkt = sniff(count=1, filter='arp')
```

and the output i recieve is:

```
WARNING: Cannot set filter: libpcap is not available. Cannot compile filter !
```

I still get a packet that was sniffed, but for some reason the filter is not working.

I am running Mac OS Big Sur. I have libpcap installed using Homebrew and I have tcpdump installed using Homebrew.

I also saw online that you could manually initialize pcap on Scapy using

```
conf.use_pcap = True
```

However when I type this in I get:

```
WARNING: No libpcap provider available ! pcap won't be used
```

I'm sure it is just a small fix but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. If anyone can help that would be amazing!

Comment: i have the same issue, installing kali linux through vbox, should run smoothly there...

Answer (score 0):

#### tldr:

```
$ brew install libpcap
$ ln -s /usr/local/opt/libpcap/lib/libpcap.a /usr/local/lib/libpcap.a
$ ln -s /usr/local/opt/libpcap/lib/libpcap.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpcap.dylib
```

#### Explanation (applicable for Python 3.9.1, Scapy 2.4.5 @ Big Sur and libpcap installed by brew):

When you debug the Scapy `sniff` function, after a while you get to *scapy.libs.winpcapy*, line 36:

```
_lib_name = find_library("pcap")
```

`find_library` is located in *ctypes.util*, for POSIX it starts on line 72. On line 73 you can see that the library is expected as one of these filenames `['libpcap.dylib', 'pcap.dylib', 'pcap.framework/pcap']`, being fed to *dyld_find*.

`dyld_find` is located in *ctypes.macholib.dyld* on line 121. If you iter through the chain on line 125 yourself, you find out that *dyld_find* is trying to succeed with one of these paths:

```
/usr/local/lib/
/Users/<user>/lib/
/usr/local/lib/
/lib/
/usr/lib/
```

In my case none of them contained the libpcap lib, which is installed in different location by brew.
The library sits in `/usr/local/opt/libpcap/lib/`.
And here you go, you just need to get the file `libpcap.dylib` (nothing wrong with `libpcap.a` too) into one of those paths searched by *dyld_find*. The two soft links above are one of a few more possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Python 3 assume that, on macOS, all shared libraries are in files located in one of a number of directories.

That is *not* the case in Big Sur; instead, a cache file is generated for system shared libraries, and at least some of the libraries from which the cache file is generated are *not* shipped with the OS.

This is one of the issues in [CPython issue 41100](https://bugs.python.org/issue41100), "Support macOS 11 and Apple Silicon Macs"; the fix is to look in the shared library cache as well as in the file system.

That issue says

> Thank you to everyone who contributed to this major undertaking!  A particular thank you to Lawrence for doing much of the initial work and paving the way. Now that 3.8 also supports Big Sur and Apple Silicon Macs as of the imminent 3.8.10 release, it's time to close this issue. If new concerns arise, pleasa open or use other issues.

So a sufficiently recent version of Python should fix this issue.