# Getting error cannot set filter: libpcap is not available. Cannot compile filter

Tags: python, prometheus, libpcap

I have this Python code to scrape the metrics from MySQL server and this scraper is running on `Linux 51f85403cce2 5.11.0-38-generic #42~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 28 20:41:07 UTC 2021 x86_64 Linux`

Here is the Python code I am running:

```
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Gauge
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import time
import string
from scapy.all import *
import re

def func1(select, insert, delete, update, lock):

  def pkt_callback(pkt):
    pkt.show()
    ts = int(time.time())
    if Raw in pkt:
      if 'select' in pkt.getlayer(Raw).load.lower():
        select.append(ts)
      if 'insert' in pkt.getlayer(Raw).load.lower():
        insert.append(ts)
      if 'update' in pkt.getlayer(Raw).load.lower():
        update.append(ts)
      if 'delete' in pkt.getlayer(Raw).load.lower():
        delete.append(ts)
      if 'lock' in pkt.getlayer(Raw).load.lower():
        lock.append(ts)
      print str(pkt.getlayer(Raw).load)
  
  sniff(prn=pkt_callback, filter='dst port 3306', store=0)

def statement_list(statement, ts):
    for item in statement:
      if item < ts:
        statement.remove(item)

def func2(select, insert, delete, update, lock):
  while True:
    ts = int(time.time())-30
    statement_list(select, ts)
    statement_list(insert, ts)
    statement_list(update, ts)
    statement_list(delete, ts)
    statement_list(lock, ts)
    time.sleep(1)

def func3(select, insert, delete, update, lock):
  
  start_http_server(9100)
  print 'Started on port 9100'

  select_statement = Gauge('select_statements', '')
  insert_statement = Gauge('insert_statements', '')
  delete_statement = Gauge('delete_statements','')
  update_statement = Gauge('update_statements','')
  lock_statement = Gauge('lock_statements','')

  while True:
    select_statement.set(len(select))
    insert_statement.set(len(insert))
    delete_statement.set(len(delete))
    update_statement.set(len(update))
    lock_statement.set(len(lock))
    time.sleep(1)

def runInParallel(*fns):
  with Manager() as manager:
    select = manager.list()
    insert = manager.list()
    delete = manager.list()
    update = manager.list()
    lock = manager.list()
    proc = []
    for fn in fns:
      p = Process(target=fn, args=[select, insert, delete, update, lock])
      p.start()
      proc.append(p)
    for p in proc:
      p.join()

runInParallel(func1, func2, func3)
```

I don't get it why it throws the error

```
# python mysql-stats.py 
Started on port 9100
ERROR: Cannot set filter: libpcap is not available. Cannot compile filter !
###[ Ethernet ]###
```

and  I don't get anything scraped.

Comment: Please, specify which OS do you use? Here is an explanation of how to fix it on macOS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65030510/filter-in-scapy-function-sniff-says-libpcap-is-not-available

Comment: Hello @PavelSapezhka its running on `Linux 51f85403cce2 5.11.0-38-generic #42~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 28 20:41:07 UTC 2021 x86_64 Linux`

Comment: »» libpcap is not available. Cannot compile filter «« :  For compilation purposes "libpcap" (or -lpcap) is `libpcap.so` → Please install the development package = `sudo apt install libpcap-dev` .

Comment: @KnudLarsen How did you get this? I've checked it on isolated fresh Ubuntu 20.04 - there is no need in the dev package, only binary.

Comment: Sorry, was merely a general consideration about "compiling" : I didn't check with the python  code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `libpcap` first. On Ubuntu 20.04 you can execute:

```
apt install -y libpcap0.8
```